# Can't get the regex examples in String split

Tags: java, regex, string

I can't get these examples from the [SUN tutorial of String split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

E.g. for `"boo:and:foo"`

```
Regex   Limit   Result  

o   5   { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }  
o   -2  { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }  
o   0   { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

I can't understand the result.
I read that for negative limit the pattern is applied as many times as possible and for positive limit it is applied n-1 times etc.

But I can't understand how the resulting array is formed in each case.

E.g. in first case why we have 1 "" in location `1` but 2 "" in locations `3` and `4`?
Same for the rest.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by understanding all possible splits. I think `"b"` and `":and:f"` are clear.

The empty strings came from splitting between `o`'s (`fo-""-o`,`bo-""-o`), and splitting after the last o - until the end of the string, which is again - an empty strng.

So totally we have 5 matching strings that the split can return.

If we split using 5 - we return at most 5 substrings, whcih is exactly the 5 substrings we have, resulting in the first output:

> If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied
>   at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter

If we split using -2, we return as much as possible [which is identical to 5 in this case]:

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length

If we split using 0, we return as much as possible - but we discard al the trailing empty strings:

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings
>   will be discarded

**Note:** If you want to ignore the empty strings between occurances of `o`, you should split with the regex `"o+"` - which takes as much `o`'s as possible, thus resulting in no empty strings from between `o`'s

Answer (score 5):

Case 1:

pretty straight forward

step 1: dealing with **boo:and:foo**

```
"b"  and  "o:and:foo"
```

step 2: dealing with **o:and:foo**

```
"" and ":and:foo"
```

step 3: dealing with **:and:foo**

```
":and:f" and "o"
```

step 4: dealing with **o**

```
""  and ""
```

Case 2: It is negative limit,so it tries to apply the pattern 'o' as many times as possible. Hence same as above. After that we are left with two empty strings and no more split to apply.

Case 3: 0, which is same as case 2 but it discard trailing empty strings. Hence it discards the last two strings

Comment: Why in step 2 it is `""` and `":and:foo"` and not plain `":and:foo"`?

Comment: Its a split, always two strings will be created. If there is nothing an empty string will be created. So if you are splitting a sting say "a", one has to be always empty string regardless.

Comment: (Observation: `String.split` has _very weird behavior_.)

Comment: My personal preference is [Guava's `Splitter`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter).